# How to set readonly filed for a particular field which lies in a One2Many field

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, readonly

I want to set a field readonly based on a selection field.
But the problem is that,the field lies under a One2Many field.So when I put readonly for that particular field,this error comes

> Error

```
 Uncaught Error: QWeb2 - template['ListView.rows']: Runtime Error: Error: QWeb2 - template['ListView.row']: Runtime Error: Error: Unknown field od_confirm_state_line in domain [["od_confirm_state_line","=","confirmed"]]
```

> Code

```
<page String="Landed Cost">
    <field name="cost_line">
    <tree editable="top">
       <field name="od_partner_id"/>
       <field name="od_product_id"/>
       <field name="od_label" attrs="{'readonly':[('od_confirm_state_line','=','confirmed')]}"/> 
    </tree>
    </field>
</page>
```

Here I want to make the field `od_label` readonly.

Comment: So `od_confirm_state_line` is a selection field which belongs to other model, and from the current one you can get there through a `One2many` field. The problem is that each *cost line* contains several records, each one with its own state, so my questions are: 1. Does `od_label` have to be readonly if any record is confirmed or if all records are confirmed? 2. Which is the technical name of the One2many field we're talking about?

Comment: Where is od_confirm_state_line belong ?!! and you cannot use a fields in attrs that don't exist in the view defination so if od_confirm_state_line is not on the view you will get the same error.

Comment: @forvas : Actually I have a field named `od_confirm_state_line` which is in the other model and `od_confirm_sale` is a related field which is in the same model of `cost_line`  1)It has to be readonly when the current record is confirmed
2)`cost_line`

Comment: @Cherif It belongs to the same model of `cost_line`

Comment: @Cherif It works when I put the field in view .Thanks a lot man.
Thanks forvas too for the help.

Comment: Yes because attrs is execute only on the client side so you need to provide all fields in the view or you will have that error

Comment: @Cherif Put that in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use a fields in attrs that don't exist in the view defination so if `od_confirm_state_line` is not on the view you will get the same erro.

because attrs is execute only on the client side so you need to provide all fields in the view

Answer (score 1):

The fields used in `domain` must be defined in your view:

```
<tree editable="top">
   <field name="od_partner_id"/>
   <field name="od_product_id"/>
   <!-- Add od_confirm_state_line like the following-->
   <field name="od_confirm_state_line"/>
   <field name="od_label" attrs="{'readonly':[('od_confirm_state_line','=','confirmed')]}"/> 
</tree>
```